# How to implement my student grading system inside a loop

Tags: php, mysql, loops, while-loop

This part of my code is used to award a grade to a student score whenever i request a student semester result (Course Scores). But, only a particular grade is awarded to all the scores, most times the last result that was uploaded into the students database is awarded to all the scores. When i added  period to the grade i.e

```
  $grade .= 'A';
  $grade .= 'B';
  $grade .= 'C';
  $grade .= 'D';
  $grade .= 'E';
```

all the grades were repeated in each column. So assuming a particular student took 6 courses in a semester and had a total of

```
  3 A's , 2 B's , 1 C
```

all the 6 grades were repeated on each row for the six courses.

On the HTML Table i'm generating i have the following columns

```
   Course_code
   Course_title
   Course_unit
   Score
   Grade
```

Only the first four are from values that are already in the database, the last (grade), i'm generating whenever i want to request students semester result.

```
   while ($row8 = mysql_fetch_assoc               ($query8)) {
            if ($row8['score'] >= 70) {
              $grade = 'A';
           }
            elseif ($row8['score'] >= 60) {
            $grade = 'B';
            }elseif ($row8['score'] >= 50) {
            $grade = 'C';
            }elseif ($row8['score'] >= 45) {
            $grade = 'D';
            }elseif($row8['score'] >= 40) {
            $grade = 'E';
            }else{
            $grade = 'F';
            }   
            }
```

Query8

```
    $query8 = mysql_query("SELECT  m.             score 
    FROM    maintable AS m  
    INNER JOIN students AS s ON
    m.matric_no = s.matric_no
    INNER JOIN courses AS c ON
                      m.course_code = c.course_code
   WHERE m.matric_no = '".$matric_no."'
    AND m.level = '".$level."'") 
   or die (mysql_error());
```

Table Structure

```
MAINTABLE: 
score_id 
matric_no 
session
semester_name 
course_code 
level         
score 
grade

COURSES: 
course_id 
course_code 
course_title 
course_unit

 STUDENT 
 matric_no 
 first_name 
 last_name
 other_name 
 level
```

Thanks for your patience and help. I most appreciate it.

Thanks.

Comment: It's not clear what your question is?

Comment: I want to implement a grading to the score dynamically whenever i request students score from the db.
Thanks

Comment: It's still not clear. I didn't understand the background, please give us an example of what the table (with records) looks like.

Comment: Isn't that what your first code snippet is already doing (the one with all the IFs)?

Comment: @truth I have a table for courses and informations regarding each course. Then a maintable that takes data from the courses table, and also includes columns for academic session, semester score, but does not a grades column. So whenever i query the db for a student semester result for all the courses taken in academic session (2011/2012), semester (rain)..there's supposed to be a number of rows returned as per the number of courses taken by the student. The HTML table that is made has columns for Course Name, Course Code, Course Unit, Score and Grade (which i want to generate).
Thanks

Comment: @Liquorvicar   Only a specific grade is awarded to all the scores, most
 times the last result that was uploaded into the maintable
 is awarded to all the scores.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit.

So, according to the Pastebin you linked (if I happen to give line numbers, it will be the lines I see on Pastebin), I didn't go into the whole code, but for the parts we're interested in. Your problem is that you calculate the grade for all the students, and save it always in the same variable. So that variable, when you try to print it later outside the loop, only contains the grade of the last students that passed in the loop.

`$query7` and `$query8` are the same except you don't retrieve the same fields. It's twice the job for the DB to process, so the best thing is to use only `$query7` (which contains the score as well), and delete `$query8` (lines 122 to 130).

Your grade calculation (lines 141 to 155) is in a loop on `$query8`, you don't need it as you're going to calculate one grade for one score, not all at once. So, just delete the loop, keep what's inside.

The inside of the said loop (lines 142 to 155), put it in a function, like I did in my first post:

```
function makeGrade($score) { //just a rewrite of your own code, exactly the same purpose
    if($score>=70)
        return 'A';
    if($score>=60)
        return 'B';
    if($score>=50)
        return 'C';
    if($score>=45)
        return 'D';
    if($score>=40)
        return 'E';
    return 'F';
}
```

On the lines 170 to 188, you loop on `$query7` to print the data, and on line 182 you print `$grade`. Instead of printing `$grade`, just call the function with the field "Score" that you retrieve in `$query7`:

```
echo makeGrade($row['Score']);
```

Now it should give the right grade for each student and each course. By the way, here you don't need a grade field in your DB, so you can delete it.

An alternate way of doing is to have the grade inside the DB (but anyway you don't need `$query8`). First, you need to set it when the code inserts the rows in `MAINTABLE` (some other file I suppose), using the same `makeGrade()` function (though in this case you must declare the function where both scripts can access it, like in an include file). Second, for the existing rows, you'd need to run a series of `UPDATE`, like this:

```
UPDATE MAINTABLE SET grade='A' WHERE score>=70;
UPDATE MAINTABLE SET grade='B' WHERE score>=60 AND score<70;
UPDATE MAINTABLE SET grade='C' WHERE score>=50 AND score<60;
UPDATE MAINTABLE SET grade='D' WHERE score>=45 AND score<50;
UPDATE MAINTABLE SET grade='E' WHERE score>=40 AND score<45;
UPDATE MAINTABLE SET grade='F' WHERE score<40;
```

Then you just have to add `grade` in `$query7`'s `SELECT` part, and use `$row['grade']` on line 182.

Make your choice :)

Comment: Thanks for the help. Here's an example of the html table i'm making. The column to the extreme right is for the grades, you'll notice that all the grades are 'C', but sum are suppose to be 'B' while others 'F' .
That is my problem.

http://m.box.com/view/f_1809576751

thanks a million. I appreciate it.

Comment: for any single semester a student will take several courses, but can only have a score for a course. So if he/she takes 6 courses in a semester he/she is expected to have 6 scores and hence 6 grades depending on the score for the particular course.

Comment: I'm uploading the results with a CSV file. And it only two columns.... Matric_no and score..

Comment: Then if you need a grade for each score, the code you posted seems right. If students' names are not all the same, your INSERT should be OK, so how is your UPDATE request, the one that sets the grade ? I used to do this error, forgetting the WHERE clause in an UPDATE...

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm not updating. The scores are already in the database
Please see   m.box.com/view/f_1809576751 to see what i'm talking about.

Comment: to see this i'd have to register, and do all the paperwork process that reminds me of state taxes :'(
More seriously, what you say is that when you need to enter a score in MAINTABLE, you enter the grade at the same time using INSERT ? Then could I have a look at the INSERT ? Because the code you posted _seems_ right, but the only request I see is a SELECT, and this kind of request doesn't mess up a database ;)
Otherwise, if the scores are _already_ in the DB, and you enter a grade _afterwards_, then you **have to** have an UPDATE somewhere ^^

Comment: thanks for the tremendious help...
Please see me code.... I hope i havent went over the line of help... I hope i havent. Thanks.

http://pastebin.com/s7QwCC3e

Comment: Thanks for posting the whole code, much easier now :) Well, I'm editing my answer as this requires some space to write, don't panic it's an easy error :)

Comment: Legendary answer you have given to a problem @Stock. 
Offtopic are you on FB? Can i add you. Would be a pleasure

Comment: Glad to know it helped :) For FB I don't use it anymore, I got bored of it, badly...

Answer (score 0):

Better try like this,

```
while ($row8 = mysql_fetch_assoc               ($query8)) {

echo "<td>$row['course_id']</td>";
 echo "<td>$row['course_code']</td>";
 echo "<td>$row['course_title']</td>";
 echo "<td>$row['score']</td>";
echo "<td>";
            if ($row8['score'] >= 70) {
              $grade = 'A';
           }
            elseif ($row8['score'] >= 60) {
            $grade = 'B';
            }elseif ($row8['score'] >= 50) {
            $grade = 'C';
            }elseif ($row8['score'] >= 45) {
            $grade = 'D';
            }elseif($row8['score'] >= 40) {
            $grade = 'E';
            }else{
            $grade = 'F';
            }   

echo $grade ."</td></tr>";

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not so clear. Here is a suggestion.

fetch the query results of query8 order by matric_no

```
  $lastid='-1';
   $newgrade="";
   while ($row8 = mysql_fetch_assoc($query8)) {
        if ($row8['score'] >= 70) {
          $grade = 'A';
       }
        elseif ($row8['score'] >= 60) {
        $grade = 'B';
        }elseif ($row8['score'] >= 50) {
        $grade = 'C';
        }elseif ($row8['score'] >= 45) {
        $grade = 'D';
        }elseif($row8['score'] >= 40) {
        $grade = 'E';
        }else{
        $grade = 'F';
        }   
        }   
       $mno=$row8['matric_no'];
       if(($lastid!=$mno && $lastid!='-1')) {
        echo "<tr><td>all db details</td><td>$newgrade</td></tr>"; //$newgrade has appended grades of student(identified by matric_no)
        $newgrade="";
       }
       $newgrade.=$grade;
       $lastid=$mno;
   }
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Here's an example of the html table i'm making. The column to the extreme right is for the grades, you'll notice that all the grades are 'C', but sum are suppose to be 'B' while others 'F' .
That is my problem.

http://m.box.com/view/f_1809576751

thanks a million. I appreciate it.